# How to properly structure iOS Xcode project for multipeer debugging

Tags: ios, xcode

I think I've just run headfirst into a big rookie mistake.

Here's my problem:  I've developed two iOS applications (client and server). Both the client and server projects have another couple of sub-projects embedded which are common to both projects.

The structure looks like this:

```
Client
+ subproject (logger)
+ subproject (multipeer session manager)

Server
+ subproject (logger)
+ subproject (multipeer session manager)
```

I'm trying to debug both the client and server projects at the same time - but xcode doesn't like having the same project opened twice (which I need) and so I'm having to juggle closing/opening/compiling etc etc.  While I can operate both apps at the same time(simualtor and device), the last project I open can't access the subprojects (because they are already open) and so I can only debug one at a time (although I can see log output from both).  What can I do to restructure my environment so I can debug both apps at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

XCode doesn't support open same project in two windows.

Here I have a suggestion, make `logger project`, `multipeer session manager` to two static library projects. `Server` project includes the two projects, and target depend on the .a files builded by the two library project. Then `Client` project adds a reference to the two .a files.Therefore, when you run `Server` project, will build new two .a files for `Client` project, and then run `Client` project with using .a files directly;

Comment: probably a dumb question, but if I go this way and create static libraries, can I trace through the code?

Comment: Yes you can, but still only one will be able to access the debug logger at any given time. This just adds another layer of abstraction to the code

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that Client and Server are two different project? Then you can open these two projects one by one, and run them on two different iOS device(or one on iOS device another on simulator).
If you want to launch two simulators, that seems impossible.

Comment: sorry, my question was a little unclear, hopefully the edit has helped. And yes, client / server are two separate projects

Answer (score -1):

If you've only got the one mac (sounds like it) only the last one launched will be able to log to xcodes debugger..

So perhaps you could work out another way to log than  NSLog..
Perhaps you have an Apple TV, you could put a temporary second screen airplay view controller up there for logging. Otherwise maybe in a splitviewcontroller on iPad or iPad simulator?

Comment: Like your suggestion, but dumbfounded why I didn't think of it - I do have a MacBook, so I'll dig that out and use it - after I buy a bigger desk :)

Comment: Ah well someone didn't like it :(. Glad to be of service